# File Reads And Multidimensional Arrays

Tags: php, arrays

Here is the contents of the text file I am reading

```
All Guests Listed Below

ID: SeanCarrington [x]
Name: Sean [x]
Email: Carrington [x]

ID: ChrisCarrington [x]
Name: Chris [x]
Email: Carrington [x]
```

I would like to extract the ID's of each guest so I wrote this

```
preg_match_all("/(ID: )(.*)(\[x\])/", $fileContent, $matches);
```

A print_r of `$fileContent` gives me this

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => ID: SeanCarrington [x] [1] => ID: ChrisCarrington [x] ) [1] => Array ( [0] => ID: [1] => ID: ) [2] => Array ( [0] => SeanCarrington [1] => ChrisCarrington ) [3] => Array ( [0] => [x] [1] => [x] ) )
```

My goal is to print out group 2 of each user. In other words their ID. So the goal output is

```
SeanCarrington
ChrisCarrington
```

I tried this

```
echo $matches[0][2];
echo $matches[1][2];
```

But I get this error

```
Notice: Undefined offset: 2 in /data/helios_web/ccarrin2/IT207/lab9/convertToArray.php on line 10
Notice: Undefined offset: 2 in /data/helios_web/ccarrin2/IT207/lab9/convertToArray.php on line 11
```

Comment: Try `echo $matches[2][0];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each user seems to have two groups, but these have index 0 and index 1.

```
echo $matches[0][0]; // "ID: SeanCarrington"
echo $matches[0][1]; // "ID: ChrisCarrington"
```

Since you want *just* the ID name, take a look at your array structure here:

```
[2] => Array (
    [0] => SeanCarrington
    [1] => ChrisCarrington
)
```

This group (index 2) which has two users in it, so you use index 2 *then* index 0 and 1:

```
echo $matches[2][0]; // "SeanCarrington"
echo $matches[2][1]; // "ChrisCarrington"
```

Comment: AHHH. So the first number 2 is the group, and then the second number is the index?

Comment: @gmustudent Yes, you are using a multidimensional array. The first index points to the array which you are accessing, then the second index points to the element within that array. (I made a small edit to my post to make that a little more clear.)

Comment: First off, thank you. Your explanation is very clear. Is there any way I could do a loop foreach group 2 match?

Comment: Yup! `foreach ($matches[2] as $id) { ... }`

Comment: foreach ($matches[2] as $key=>$match) { echo $match[2][$key]; } ? Sorry I'm new to this, I'm a java guy

Comment: You *could* do that, but just use the construct I showed you above; `$id` will be the variable to use. (It would be like, in Java, doing `for (String id : matches[2]) { ... }`.)